# Помогите с VBA в Access

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, access

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку из таблицы "товар" автоматически вычиталось количество товаров берущееся из таблицы "чек" при добавлении в нее записи.
[image: Табл "Товар"]

[image: Табл "Чек"]

[image: Форма заполнения таблицы "Чек"]

[image: Мой вариант решения, работает не корректно так как вычитает каждый раз количество из всех товаров, а не по текущей записи (и количество в минус уходит,хотя я сделал на это проверку)]

рис 4: Мой вариант решения, работает не корректно так как вычитает каждый раз количество из всех товаров, а не по текущей записи (и количество в минус уходит,хотя я сделал на это проверку)
рис 1: Табл "Товар"
рис 2: Табл "Чек"
рис 3: Форма заполнения таблицы "Чек"

Comment: Что-то непонятно  - спросите, а то я перечитал и понял что не очень ясно что мне нужно

Comment: Выкладывайте код текстом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте разбить задачу на части.

1. Зафиксировать выбранный чек. Например в таблицу табл_Текущий_чек вставьте данные о чеке
2. Зафиксируйте выбранную запись. Аналогично в таблицу табл_Текущая_Запись_Текущего_Чека
3. Выполните действия со строкой из временной таблицы (табл_текущая_запись_текущего_чека) и складом

Когда вы делаете много действий за раз, трудно локализовать ошибку и в чем она заключается. В предлагаемом подходн же вы сможете отладить это пошагово.

Когда разберётесь, можно уже и оптимизировать, исключать временные таблицы и т.п.